# New-WebServiceProxy vs. enumerations of autogenerated class

Tags: powershell, soap

We leverage **New-WebServiceProxy** to access the SOAP interface of multiple SAP hosts.

We've already learned from experience that New-WebServiceProxy's Namespace parameter is kinda false friend. Therefore we only reference the autogenerated class within our scripts, for example...

```
$aOptions = New-Object -TypeName "${SapHostControlNamespace}.OperationOptions"
```

... where the above SapHostControlNamespace variable holds what we've got before from *proxyobject*.GetType().Namespace

This approach works fine except for enumerations. So, the question is: Given a script with a SapHostControlNamespace variable that holds the namespace, how to work with enumerations in that situation?

This, of course, won't work:

```
[$SapHostControlNamespace.InstanceOptionsFlags]::OSERVICE
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-as` type conversion operator to obtain a reference to the type:

```
$flagType  = "${SapHostControlNamespace}.InstanceOptionsFlags" -as [type]
$enumValue = $flagType::OSERVICE
```

or use [`Enum.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse) and let PowerShell implicitly handle the conversion to `[type]`:

```
$enumValue = [enum]::Parse("${SapHostControlNamespace}.InstanceOptionsFlags", 'OSERVICE')
```